# How to package vips for distribution?

Tags: macos, binaries, vips, software-packaging, libvips

I am trying to package the vips repository for distribution so I can double-click on it and install it on any Mac OS version. On Windows, this is easy - I just have to put the folder containing the binaries in the package. For Mac OS, I need to compile the binaries specific to each version of the OS.

I have tried to use the binaries generated by `brew install vips` and `sudo port install vips`, but as you can imagine, I cannot use these since they are specific to the OS. The only way I thought one could do this, is by installing from source.

Could you please give instructions on how to **compile the binaries of vips from source** (including the libraries it depends on) **on Mac OS** or provide any other methods by which I can create a distribution file? Thank you!

I am using Mac OS 13, M1.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do it like this:

https://github.com/jcupitt/build-osx

That uses jhbuild to make a complete stack to a private prefix, and then package it as a `.app`.

But I've not touched it for ages, perhaps there's a better way now.